# jquery load does nothing, no console errors

Tags: jquery

Below is my FULL code.  I must be doing something dumb.  I've used this before... it's shouldn't be the single origin policy as I'm actually running it from the server, not locally.  I get ZERO console errors.  If I put a breakpoint on the load statement it *does* hit it.

**http://mysite.com/reports/PendingFulfillment.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>All Requests Pending Fulfillment</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //$("#Content").load("http://mysite.com/somelongdynamicwpfurlIreallywanttoload #documentBody");
        $("#Content").load("http://mysite.com/reports/index.html"); // <-- simplified for testing
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All Requests Pending Fulfillment</h1>
    <div id="Content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you select the element, that element is not added to the DOM yet, you should put your code within document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Content").load("http://mysite.com/reports/index.html"); 
})
```

Comment: Yeah I just came back here to post that I had realized this is what I was forgetting.  :facepalm:

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to either be moved to the end of the document or placed within a document.ready call. You're attempting to execute the code before the page and `#Content` element has been loaded.

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Content").load("http://mysite.com/reports/index.html"); // <-- simplified for testing
});
```